One-page website wont scroll to the specific div on mobile
I have some problems with the scrolling to each sections on a one-pageesite.
Click here to view the demo site
If you check the page on pc, you will see, when clicking a menu item in the header, the page will scroll to the right place.
But, on mobile, it also scrolls to the right place, but it will scroll more, then it is as necessary.
The sections have some classes, that make some padding in them.
I have removed these paddings, but it didnt solve the problem.

Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?

What do you mean by ‘mobile’, a specific device and OS or small viewport or…?
